# An unknown error

Tags: xetex, errors, compilation-error

I cannot locate the error here. Below I give the error. This is a critical tex file for me to be compiled, please help.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mathabx}

%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%%\let\circ\undefined
%%\let\diamond\undefined
%\let\bullet\undefined
%%\let\ring\undefined
%\let\emptyset\undefined
%\let\owns\undefined


%\usepackage{mathabx}


%\usepackage{xypic}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\pullbackcorner}[1][dl]{\save*!/#1-1pc/#1:(1,-1)@^{|-}\restore}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\newfontfamily\ngg{NewGardiner}
% \usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{babyloniannum}
%\setfont{NewGardiner}
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]

%\newfontfamily\nggg{Egyptian Hieroglyphs}[Ligatures=TeX]

%  Scale=MatchUppercase,
%  Script={Egyptian Hieroglyphs}]

  %UprightFeatures={Ligatures=Common}]


%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}}
%\newcommand{\stheenumm}{\babyloniannum{1}}

%\newcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\babyloniannum{enumi}}
\MakeRobust\babyloniannum
\MakeRobust\hgnum
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@moduloitem #1
  {
   \ngg
    \char
     \int_eval:n
      {
        \int_mod:nn{\int_use:c{#1}}{\modulolength}
        +
        \exp_args:No\int_from_hex:n{\modulostart}
      }
  }
\newcommand\moduloitem[1]{\@moduloitem{c@#1}}
\newcommand\modulostart{13000}   %adapt
\newcommand\modulolength{1000}      %adapt
\AddEnumerateCounter{\moduloitem}{\@moduloitem}{AA}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--{\ngg\symbol{"\the\value{nw}}}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ngg\symbol{"\the\value{\stepcounter{nw}}}}


%\usepackage{mathabx}

%\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

%\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$\ggg$
%\show\babyloniannum

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\babyloniannum{enumi}}

% \xymatrix{A \ar[r] &B}

%      $$
%  \xymatrix@=3pc{
%    & & D \\
%    B \ar[r]\ar@/^/[rru]^{h} & P \ar[ru] \pullbackcorner & \\
%    A \ar [u]^f \ar[r]_g & C \ar[u]\ar@/_/[ruu]_{k} &
%  }
%  $$


\underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$}
\bigskip
\bigskip
% \begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{\theenumi}--\moduloitem{enumi}]

 \begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\hgnum{\theenumi}--\moduloitem{enumi}]

  \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
  \item *vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
  \item svoboda a volnost
  \def\tmp{j}
  \item \if \tmp j c\fi \vbox{\hbox{Two lines}\hbox{of type.}}

\newwrite\jhfile
\openout\jhfile=test.jh
\newcommand{\triplex}{XXX}
\write\jhfile{test \triplex test}

\newcommand{\demoletter}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\phantom{#1}}}}

%\demoletter{O}\demoletter{n}\demoletter{e}
%\demoletter{l}\demoletter{i}\demoletter{n}\demoletter{e}\demoletter{.}




  \item teorie množin (a někdy i další) je manipulace s objekty "ode zdi ke zdi" a jejich sledování
  \item nějak to být musí
  \item všechno je skoro tak nejlepší a nejbohatší, jak to být může
  \item všechno lze rozvrstvit do podúrovní
  \item být ve středu vyprávění a ne
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**ERROR**

```
Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje36.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

xelatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(ideje36.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/accents\accents.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikz-cd.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzli
brarymatrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzli
braryquotes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.cod
e.tex))) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3deprecation.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW3\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list
                                                  
? 

! Emergency stop.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list
                                                  
No pages of output.

_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Is everything up to date?  Start by commenting out whatever you think doesn't cause the error, until you end up with a minimal file that still has the error.  The parentheses in the log file suggest that the problem is fontspec, but XeLaTeX should work fine with that.

Comment: recreate your formats (in the miktex console).

Comment: Dear all, I have had a damaged WinEdt 10.3 and MikTeX instalations. Now fixed. Thank you for not blaming me for not giving MWE.

Comment: @user2925716 is this question answered?